# How to find ClientId in aspx(javascript) that the control is in the template

Tags: asp.net

```
        function CheckRequired(target, value) {
        if ($("#<%=rbWaiveyes.ClientId %>").attr("checked") || $("#<%=rvWaiveno.ClientId %>").attr("checked")) {
            value.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            value.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

I want to get rbWaiveyes and rvWaiveno ID, the script works in ordinary way.
but the rbWaiveyes  and rvWaiveno  are actually in the template of gridview.
what we do in the c# file is that we can use findcontrol method, but how can i find id in the aspx(javascript) way.

And the this is actually custom validater control which is also put in the template, so call is also from template.

Comment: Where you call this function CheckRequired?

Comment: Check the syntax by changing it like this $("#<%= rbWaiveyes.ClientID %>")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function CheckRequired(target, value) {
     value.IsValid = $(target).parents("td").find(".waiveRadioButton :radio:checked").length > 0; }


 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbWaiveyes" Text="Yes" CssClass="waiveRadioButton"
         GroupName='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' />&nbsp;
     <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbvWaiveno" Text="No" CssClass="waiveRadioButton"
         GroupName='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
     <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cv1" 
         ValidationGroup='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'
         ClientValidationFunction="CheckRequired" ErrorMessage="Make your choice" />
     <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Ok" ValidationGroup='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'
         CommandName="Save" /> </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use id selector here as for each row ids of rbWaiveyes and rvWaiveno will be different. Try this code instead:

```
function CheckRequired(target, value) {
    value.IsValid = $(target).parents("td").find(".waiveRadioButton :radio:checked").length > 0;
}

<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbWaiveyes" Text="Yes" CssClass="waiveRadioButton"
        GroupName='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' />&nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbvWaiveno" Text="No" CssClass="waiveRadioButton"
        GroupName='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cv1" 
        ValidationGroup='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'
        ClientValidationFunction="CheckRequired" ErrorMessage="Make your choice" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Ok" ValidationGroup='<%# "Waive_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'
        CommandName="Save" />
</ItemTemplate>
```